# Transformation of a covariance matrix to one with more or less "extreme" diagonals

Tags: matrices, covariance, positive-definite

Assume $\Sigma$ is a valid correlation matrix in $p$ dimensions.  (It could be a covariance matrix, but I'd rather keep ones on the diagonals if possible to keep things simple).

Is there a procedure or function that takes $\Sigma$ and operates on it to form a valid covariance matrix with off-diagonal elements that are always either further from zero, or that have moved in the direction of zero?

For example, say that 
$$
\Sigma = \left[\begin{array}[c c] 
c 1 & .5\\
.5 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

an example of the values becoming more "extreme" would be

$$
\Sigma_E = \left[\begin{array}[c c] 
c 1 & .8\\
.8 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

An example of them becoming less "extreme" would be

$$
\Sigma_e = \left[\begin{array}[c c] 
c 1 & -.5\\
-.5 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
or 
$$
\Sigma_e = \left[\begin{array}[c c] 
c 1 & .1\\
.1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

In multiple dimensions, the criterion would be that each off-diagonal $\rho$ would be multiplied by some factor greater than 1 in the "more extreme" case, or less than 1 in the "less extreme" case.  Of course, the problem is that an arbitrarily chosen set of factors can lead to negative definite matrices.

What is a procedure that is guaranteed to return a valid covariance matrix as per the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the only requirement for a "valid covariance matrix" is that the matrix should have $1$s on the diagonal and be positive definite.

With that being said: for any covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and any real number $t$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$, the matrix
$$
(1-t) \Sigma + tI
$$
is necessarily a valid covariance matrix ($I$ here is the identity matrix).  In fact, this gives you a sliding scale which brings the off diagonal elements to $0$ as $t \to 1$.

---

Here's a nice way to go in the other direction: if you can compute the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$ (so $\Sigma$ would need to be *strictly* positive definite, not just semidefinite), we could compute
$$
\frac{\Sigma - tI}{1-t}
$$
where $0 \leq t \leq \lambda$.

I'm not sure how to make things "more extreme" when $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite (at least, how to do so while guaranteeing that the diagonal entries are still $1$).  However, it should be possible to do so whenever $\Sigma$ has rank at least $2$.

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something, this can't make the off-diagonals bigger, only smaller.

Comment: That's right.  There's no way to make the off-diagonals bigger (and stay positive definite) without finding some kind of eigenvalue/eigenvector first.

Comment: Nothing stopping me finding eigenvalues...

Comment: All right, I'll think about that then

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar.  Care to elaborate on your thought process?  Matrix algebra is still fairly magical to me.

Comment: The real insight, I think, is that we can make the off-diagonals smaller by bringing a matrix "closer to the identity.  From there, I used the well known (but tremendously useful) facts that the eigenvalues of $A + tI$ are just $\lambda + tI$ (for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$), and that of course $A + tI$ will be symmetric if $A$ is symmetric.  Another way to think about this is to note that the set of positive (semi)definite matrices is convex, so their convex combinations always produce a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: Sorry, that's $\lambda + t$ for the eigenvalues